# Is there a way I can use sumproduct in Microsoft Excel to select multiple values in a column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumproduct

I would like to use sumproduct (open to any other method as well) in excel to filter array values from a data table. Instead of just filtering a column for a single value, I want to filter column D for whether each row value "is in" the values in column A. Here is a sample of my data:

| A | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Algebra II | 127281693 | Algebra II | T1 | 97 |
| Physics | 127281693 | Physics | YR | 89 |
| AP US History | 127281693 | AP US History | F1 | 78 |
| Korean III | 127281693 | Korean III | YR | 64 |
|  | 127281694 | Tutoring | YR | 87 |
|  | 127281694 | AP Computer Science A | YR | 99 |
|  | 127281694 | Algebra II | YR | 81 |
|  | 127281694 | Biology | F3 | 78 |
|  | 127281694 | Biology | YR | 59 |

I am using the following formula to filter for C = 127281694, D = Algebra II, E = YR, and F < 100:
`=SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$10=127281694)*($D$2:$D$10=$A$2)*($E$2:$E$10="YR")*($F$2:$F$10<100)*1)`. The formula correctly returns the value of 1, as there is one row that meets these conditions.

Instead of filtering for just D = Algebra II, I want to filter if D "is in" a list of values, such as {"Algebra II", "Physics", "AP US History", "Korean III"}, so that the array will return all rows where column D = Algebra II OR Physics OR AP US History OR Korean III. Does anyone know a solution for this problem?

Comment: What would be final result then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably has to be entered as an [array formula](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula) if you don't have dynamic arrays:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$10=127281693)*(IFNA(MATCH(D2:D10,A2:A10,0)/MATCH(D2:D10,A2:A10,0),0))*($E$2:$E$10="YR")*($F$2:$F$10<100))
```

[image: Screenshot illustrating proposed formula]

(I chose an alternative value for `C` so that there would be more than 1 result)

Comment: Great. Yes, like this. a small question: Is the fraction really needed? afaik, MATCH returns n/a if no match found?

Comment: @Anonymous Yes, the division is required to maintain a binary result from the 'subject match' (without it, values greater than 1 would be returned which would 'inflate' the overall `SUMPRODUCT()` result)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filer all rows that D column contain values from column A then use below formula-

```
=FILTER(B1:E9,COUNTIFS(A1:A4,C1:C9))
```

From your given formula in post. You can use below formula to return rows as per multiple criteria (Yellow highlighted).

```
=FILTER(B1:E9,COUNTIFS(A1:A4,C1:C9)*(B1:B9=127281694)*(D1:D9="YR")*(E1:E9<100))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could add another column to check if the respective single row value of column D XMATCHes with any row of column A.
Then use this new column as another criteria in your formula.

If it works out, you can integrate it directly into your formula w/o having the additional column.